# How to fix cell history in cell note?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I found a script that's supposed to add cell history in a note, the original one found here(https://www.pbainbridge.co.uk/2019/07/add-note-to-cell-on-google-sheet-edit.html) does not work or I'm doing something wrong. I modified the script and is supposed to add notes to cells in Column 18(R) seems to work but only on one of my sheets and it works properly only on page 2, in page 1 it makes a note but with no content other than date. Any help to fix is greatly appreciated!

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getColumn() === 18) {
      var ss = e.source; 
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var range = e.range;
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var currentCellValue = activeCell.getValue();
  var currentCellNote = activeCell.getNote();
  Logger.log('Current cell value is: ' + currentCellValue);
   
  Logger.log('Current Note contains: ' + currentCellNote);
 range.setNote('Last Modified: ' + new Date() + '\n' + 'Cell Value: ' + "'" + currentCellValue + "'" + '\n\n' + currentCellNote);
    
  }
```

Comment: Where are you closing your `if` statement? And what exactly are you trying to do with column 18?. Please read [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The script can close after whats posted above. I have it as part of other peices. But regardless the purpose of this alone is to automatically keep a record of info in cells on column 18. So any edit made, the note updates with what it currently has and what its had before. To make question clear, its "how to add cell history in a note?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const A1=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).getA1Notation();
  const rg=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,18);
  const dt=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
  const newNote=Utilities.formatString('Last Modified:%s cell:%s Value:%s\n',dt,A1,e.value);
  rg.setNote(rg.getNote() + newNote);
}
```

Comment: Question, how can I use this for multiple columns? I tried adding column numbers but doesn't work the same way. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Modify the iF statement

Comment: It's rather difficult to assist you if you don't share what you tried.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  Please add the new code to your question

Comment: trying to have same code work for different columns. in this case 18&21. I've tried repeating same code one after another and simply changing columns in line: const rg=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,18); -- also Ive tried adding if before each code but code seems to work perfectly when its for one column.

Comment: The last post is total nonsense.  You obviiously don't understand how to use the getRange() method.

Comment: If you know you don’t then you need to read the documentation until you do