# How to auto add a note containing cell history in a triggered cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently the following script automatically adds a note in column A cells containing its history, at the same time it automatically adds todays date to the cell next to it in column B (in sheet titled "1"). I would want the note to be added in the triggered cell (Column B), not cells in column A. It would also be useful to create individual notes in each column as well. Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks in advance!
Here is the script:

```
function onEdit(e){
{
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var A1=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).getA1Notation();
    if( sh.getName() == "1") {
  var rg=sh.getActiveCell();
      if( rg.getColumn() == 1 ) {
        var nextCell = rg.offset(0, 1);
  nextCell.setValue(new Date());
        
  var dt=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
  var newNote=Utilities.formatString('Last Modified:%s cell:%s Value:%s\n',dt,A1,e.value);
  rg.setNote(rg.getNote() + newNote);
}  
}  
  }}
```

Comment: Did you get your snippet form here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64750953/how-to-fix-add-cell-history-in-cell-note Besides copy and paste, what have you tried? Can you update the variable names so they are easier to read? i.e what is rg supposed to represent?

Comment: That was a separate and different question I had. This script is modified and is a combination of that and what pertains to this question which is auto input of a value in this case a date. I've tried multiple modifications to add note in a different cell other than one directly edited. This is a working script, test in a sheet if you want, rg is edited cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you posted should work fine if you remove the conditions (if), since you don't want to restrict it to a particular column. For example:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var A1=e.range.getA1Notation();
  
  var editDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  
  var nextCell = e.range.offset(0, 1);
  nextCell.setValue(editDate);
  
  var newNote=Utilities.formatString('Last Modified: %s / Updated Cell: %s / Updated Cell Value: %s / Associated Date Cell: %s / Associated Date Cell Value: %s\n',editDate,A1,e.value,nextCell.getA1Notation(),editDate);
  nextCell.setNote(nextCell.getNote() + newNote);
}
```

Comment: Correct this works to add a note to cell being edited, what happens with the script I shared is that the cell next to it adds a value, in this case a date. I would want that cell (the one next to it) to create its own note with its own history.

Comment: So you want the notes to be added to the cell on the right (?), instead of to the modified cell itself?

Comment: No, I have managed to do that. what I want is this, example: if I enter "test" in cell A1, automatically todays date is created in B1. I would want the note to be created in B1 (the date) not the value A1 has.

Comment: Please check the updated script. It creates a note on the cell to the right of the edited cell and it updates that note's text every time the target cell is updated.

Comment: I appreciate the help, that though creates a note with value of A1 in B1. I want B1's automated value to be in the note.

Comment: B1's automated value is the same as the value written in "Last Modified", since that date is written to both B1 and to each note. In any case, I've updated the code to just write everything, so then you can remove what you don't want from it to better suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks alot! Slightly modified and it works perfect.